# jquery .live(), event binding and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a few buttons and select box. When i click on a button its sending ajax request and returning `{"ids":{"attr_id":"1","subattr_id":"6"}}`
`attr_id` here is value that i set to selectbox. According to `attr_id` generated second select box, which value need to set to `subattr_id`.
`.onClick()` button event :

```
$.post(
    function(result){
        jQuery(result.ids).each(function(){
        var prodAttr = $(this).attr('attr_id');
        $('div.attribute_wrapper select.property').change(function(e,eType){
          if(eType == 'click')
          {
              prodSubattr = $(result.ids).attr('subattr_id');
              $(this).trigger('cascadeSelect',prodAttr);
              //select.subProperty generated by ajax when first selectbox changed
              $('select.subProperty').trigger('setValue',prodSubattr);
          }
        });
        $('div.attribute_wrapper select.property').trigger('change',e.type);
        $('select.subProperty').live('setValue', function(e, subAttr){
            $(this).val(subAttr);
        });
     });
   }
)
```

Value of second selectbox didnt changing.
So i need some help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

setValue isn't an event. Consider creating a function and calling that instead.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: setValue is my custom event, which i want to triggered when 1st selectbox changed.